# ORA-30036: unable to extend segment by 8 in undo tablespace 'UNDOTBS3'

Tags: oracle, plsql

Oracle is throwing this error when dropping and creating a table I regularly do without problem.

```
ORA-12801: error signaled in parallel query server P000, instance MyURL:bwup (3)
ORA-30036: unable to extend segment by 8 in undo tablespace 'UNDOTBS3'
```

I would like to understand conceptually what is happening here and how could I fix this without autoextending the tablespace. I've purged the DB in order to cleanse the space occupied by those recoverable tables recently dropped and stopped throwing the error, but I don't understand why. Is that tablespace that Oracle is talking about common for different processes?

Comment: what version of Oracle are you using ? do you have flashback enabled ?

Comment: How are you recreating the table?  I'm assuming that involves running a relatively expensive and/or long-running query?  Are the tables you're querying being modified by other processes in the meantime?

Comment: @RobertoHernandez Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production. I've just asked my DBA to check, but it may well be since I did a test enabling the flashback some days ago. Will come back to you on it.

Comment: @JustinCave no, I run the query every day and it runs pretty quickly. It must be something else this time.

Comment: we really need to see code, ie, *how* you are doing the create/population